# Changing view-port max width

Tags: html, css, viewport

Is there a way to change the maximum width of the container(body or html or etc...) so that in a larger screen I can maintain the sizes of the elements as they are in a maximum width screen?

I've been using 'vw' for all the dimensions and want to know whether there is a way to set a maximum size for a 'vw' unit.

Comment: Good question, but even if you were to set the max-width on the body, the `vw` unit would remain the same. This is likely to create problems with your layout. You'd have to set a max pixel (or em, or percentage) width on the vw unit itself, which is probably only possible with scripting.

Comment: yep. that's the problem. I tried changing container element widths. Either no change or too much change. I thought there could be a way people use to overcome this. Thanks for the reply.